# How to tell in code if Webpack build was Production (-p) or Development/Debug (-d)

Tags: webpack

The docs seem to suggest there is an API `DEBUG`, but this doesn't seem to be defined. What am I missing? https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/api-in-modules#debug

Also, how does React know which mode it was built in, for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/), `webpack -p` is the equivalent of `webpack --optimize-minimize --define process.env.NODE_ENV="'production'"`, which add to your plugin stack the following setting:

```
 new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
 })
```

Since it replaces any occurrence of `process.env.NODE_ENV` in your code with `'production'`, it enables you to tell if you are building with webpack in production mode.

React also [relies on the same environment variable](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#webpack).

Comment: It doesn't actually do that though, `process` in my code is undefined.

Comment: And what about `process.env`? Remember that `process.xxx` references are just replaced with their actual value.

Comment: You're right. It replaces `process.env.NODE_ENV` but not `process` or `process.env`, which will be undefined in the browser. But the whole expression works, just makes it quite impossible make the check error tolerant.